# Extract a formatted number from a string

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract a number from a string, the string is like `1,239 peoples`. I need an output of `1239` from the above string. I used the following cheap method for extracting that number....

```
$text='1,239 peoples';
$text=str_replace(',','',$text);
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $text, $matches);
echo $matches[0][0];
```

Is there any better solution fo that..thanks in advance...

Comment: `preg_match_all('!\d+!', str_replace(',','',$text), $matches);`. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace everything that is not a number in the string with nothing, which gives you a string with just the number.

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "", $string);
echo $string;
```

Comment: Why not using `\D+` instead?

Answer (score 1):

A safer way is to first extract that you want, after **and only after** give it the good format, example:

```
if (preg_match('~\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?~', $string, $match))
    $result = str_replace(',', '', $match[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//This will replace anything that is not a number with a blank string.
$number = preg_replace("#[^0-9]*#", "", "1,123");
```

Becareful with "1,233.90" though.